# In Sitecore 9.3, SuppressFormValidation is not available, what is the replacement?

Tags: pipelines

We are upgrading from Sitecore 8.2 to 9.3.
In our 8.2 solution, there is a patch created with the type `SuppressAdfsFormValidation`

```
<sitecore>
   <pipelines>
      <preprocessRequest>
         <processor patch:instead="*[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.PreprocessRequest.SuppressFormValidation, Sitecore.Kernel']" type="Sample.Pipelines.PreprocessRequest.SuppressAdfsFormValidation, Sample" />
      </preprocessRequest>
   </pipelines>
</sitecore>
```

which inherits `PreProcessRequestProcessor` and here is the implementation provided below:

```
public class SuppressAdfsFormValidation : PreprocessRequestProcessor
{
    public override void Process(PreprocessRequestArgs args)
    {
        Assert.ArgumentNotNull(args, "args");

        try
        {
            new SuppressFormValidation().Process(args);
        }
        catch (HttpRequestValidationException)
        {
            string rawUrl = args.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl;
            if (!rawUrl.Contains("sample item") && !rawUrl.Contains("secure") && !rawUrl.Contains("login"))
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

We could not find the `SuppressFormValidation()` in

```
Sitecore.Kernel.dll(14.0.0.0) -> Sitecore.Pipelines.PreProcessRequestProcessor
```

Could you please suggest if there is any alternative to implement this feature?

Comment: Welcome to Sitecore Stack Exchange. In sitecore 8.2 you used this functionality to supress the .NET form validation exception? If you remove the processor completely you are still getting errors in 9.3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this processor was added only for sitecore 8 because the asp.net request validation has been changed in .NET 4.0 and it was breaking the content editor, if you take a look at the current implementation you'll see that this processor is introduced for this:

```
Suppresses the form validation excheption that has been introduced in .NET 4.0 for Sitecore backend.
```

Please also take a look at the post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9114276/request-validation-how-and-why-is-it-disabled-in-sitecore and the sitecore KB article https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0031258.

However this processor is disabling completely the validation and if you would write cross site queries like `?<script>alert('attack');</script>` the page would still load normally. To fix this you would have needed to override the processor like described here https://www.loic-rabehaja.com/sitecore-blog/2015/6/2/prevent-xss-attack-on-sitecore-cms-use-of-in-built-net-validation. Hence it was removed in newer sitecore versions and I wouldn't recommend to preserve this functionality after you upgrade.

If you need to disable the request validation I think you should try to handle it at the page level instead of the whole website.